# What is a UART port

Tags: linux, tty, serial-port, cubieboard

I have a `.fex` file for Cubietruck. Supposedly, the bluetooth pins are defined in the `uart_para2`. With the current config, I have `uart0` and `uart2` enabled, and everything else is disabled. Bluetooth functions fine under such condition.

Then, I changed the `.fex` file by simply renaming `[uart_para2]` to `[uart_para3]` and vice-verca (renaming `uart3` to `uart2`). The new "uart2" (or the old "uart3") is still disabled.

Now bluetooth does not work anymore. `dmesg | grep tty` still shows that `uart3` is mounted on `/dev/ttyS1`.

So what is UART and why does the label matter? I thought it's a label and nothing more, but evidently not.

Answer (score 1):

A UART is a Universal Asynchronous Receiver and Transmitter.  It is a device which takes parallel bits of data, as found in the computer, and serializes them to send over a medium such as a wire or the airwaves.  It also takes data in in serial form and assembles it into a parallel form to be used in the computer.  Here is the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) and here is [another good explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105290/what-happens-under-the-hood-when-some-data-is-sent-received-on-an-uart-or-simil).  For even more information follow J F Sebastian's link in that page.